# After developing a facebook app for the timeline how do we submit the app to the timeline directory? Or do we just take it out of sandbox mode?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-apps

When we are ready to take our app out of sandbox mode, is there a procedure for submitting an open graph app to the timeline directory? or will taking it out of sanbox mode make the app 'findable' to others. We would like the app to appear on the facebook timeline directory as shown here - http://www.facebook.com/about/timeline/apps

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. take your app our of sandbox mode
2. grow it to over 10 MAU and it'll automatically get indexed in Search.

See https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/523/

Timeline apps are just apps which have been enabled for Open Graph, so the process is no different.

If you want a listing of Timeline apps to try, checkout: https://www.facebook.com/about/timeline/apps

Answer (score 1):

You need to take it off the sandbox mode, and also turn on the *Social Discovery* as noted in the [Apps on Facebook.com tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/).
You should also read about the *Social Channels* in that tutorial.

As for the timeline/apps, I'm not sure how those apps got there, but I think it's something facebook control and it's not automatic, that is they chose to put those apps there, for some reason.